# Exploding strings in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, explode

I have the following bit of PHP code.

Ultimately, I'd like to store `<p>Michael is 26</p>` in the **$str1** variable and `<p>He likes green cars.</p><p>And white footballs</p><p>And red lollies</p><p>And yellow suns</p>` in the **$str2** variable.

So basically everything in the first paragraph goes in **$str1** and **everything** thereafter goes in **$str2**.

```
<?php
    $str = "<p>Michael is 26</p><p>He likes green cars.</p><p>And white footballs</p><p>And red lollies</p><p>And yellow suns</p>";
    $strArray = explode('</p>', $str);
    $str1 = $strArray[0] . '</p> ';
    echo $str1;
    // variable to export remainder of string (minus the $str1 value) ?
?>
```

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `explode` with a delimiter:

```
 explode('</p>', $str, 2);
```

This will return:

```
array (
   0 => '<p>Michael is 26',
   1 => '<p>He likes green cars.</p><p>And white footballs</p><p>And red lollies</p><p>And yellow suns</p>' 
)
```

So then all you have to do is:

```
$strArray = explode('</p>', $str, 2);
$str1 = $strArray[0] . '</p> ';
$str2 = $strArray[1];
echo $str1.$str2; //will output the original string again
```

Answer (score 3):

No `explode()` is necessary here. Simple string operations (`strpos(), substr()`)will do fine:

```
$str = "<p>Michael is 26</p><p>He likes green cars.</p><p>And white footballs</p><p>And red lollies</p><p>And yellow suns</p>";
$str1 = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "</p>") + strlen("</p>"));
$str2 = substr($str, strpos($str, "</p>") + strlen("</p>"));

echo $str1;
// <p>Michael is 26</p>
echo $str2;
// <p>He likes green cars.</p><p>And white footballs</p><p>And red lollies</p><p>And yellow suns</p>
```

Comment: `substr()` and `strpos()` may be slower and why should he use it if with `explode()` he can achieve same result easier? :)

Comment: minor modification is to remove the magic number 4, and replace it with strlen("</p>").

Comment: nice solution!!! I prefer this one, it does what its intended to do, and not exploding, imploding, etc... the code it's clear

Answer (score 0):

using your code, appending this should do the job

```
unset($strArray[0]);

$str2 = implode('</p>', $strArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_split`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_split) for this, unlike `explode` it allows to just look where to split. And it supports a limit as well:

```
list($str1, $str2) = preg_split('~(?<=</p>)~', $str, 2);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/ubFnMeKN)